# Listen multiple documents in firestore, It's ids are stored in an array

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a cart for e commerce using firestore. Cart document is downloaded and products ids are stored in an array. Now i want to listen these products documents for data changes like price, quantity etc.

My firestore database design as given below.

```
-ProductCollection
   -{product_id}
       document
       |-name
       |-price
       |-availableSizes
       |    -1
       |      -name
       |      -quantityAvailable
       |    -2
       |      -name
       |      -quantityAvailable
-CartCollection
   -{cart_id}
     document
      |-ItemList
      |   -{product_id}
      |      -size
      |         -quntityNeeded
      |      -size
      |         -quntityNeeded
      |   -{product_id}
      |      -size
      |         -quntityNeeded
      |      -size
      |         -quntityNeeded
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please also add your database structure.

Comment: Please see again my reuqest from my frist comment.

Comment: I am trying the same thing but no solution yet.